# How to remove/destroy Backbone View which is appended to body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I have this backbone App, where a new View is triggered by click event and appended to the DOM's body, as a popup. My issue is though, that I want the new View to be removed completely when I click outside the View. Here is the event which triggers the new View:

view1.js:

```
events: {
    'click .btn': 'popupView'
},
popupView: function(){
  new popup.View().render();
}
```

Then the code to my "popup" view:

```
popup.View = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: 'some_template',  
    initialize: function(){
        this.$el.appendTo("body");
        this.render();
    },

    afterRender: function(){
        $("body").click(function(){
            $('div.wrap').remove(); // removes the wrap div from the html template
            this.remove() // does not work
    })

})
```

The thing is, that as soon I click on the body after the popup view got rendered, it removes the wrapping div html from the DOM, but when i open the popup view again, the previous HTML gets rendered twice etc etc. So, that indicates, that the View has not been removed/destroyed after all.

Any suggestion how to solve this? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

That's because `this` context is different inside the callback function. Try that:

```
afterRender: function(){
    var that = this;
    $("body").click(function(){
        $('div.wrap').remove();
        that.remove(); // should work
})
```

Let me know if this works

Comment: Hmm no, unfortunately this doesnt work. Same behaviour... :-/

Comment: What if you tried removing `$('div.wrap').remove();`? `Backbone.View`'s `remove` method [deletes the html](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove)

I'll update my answer if that works.